# tSQL - convert nvarchar(8) to time only

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

***I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to manipulate Public transport system database.***
I have a table in database named 'dbo.tblStop_times', two columns of which should be of data type **time**. At the moment, they are both nvarchar and they have data stored in a pattern like this - `"07:39:00"` (without quotes)
I had same question with date columns as well, but found a solution for that on stackoverflow just few hours back.

Below works fine for conversion of nvarchar column to date column.

```
ALTER TABLE tblCalendar ALTER COLUMN [start_date] DATE NOT NULL;
```

I am not sure if what I want is achievable or not, because the above mention conversion works just fine, I assume it might be possible.

What I have atm is - `nvarchar(8)`, what I want it to be is `sql time data type`, something like **hh:mm:ss** [and if possible - without trailing nnnnnn - nanoseconds component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
ALTER TABLE tblStop_times ALTER COLUMN start_time TIME NOT NULL;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/LOUP20532) is a rextester.

EDIT:

If you don't have valid time values, then you have a problem.  You should first look for the values:

```
select col
from tblStop_times
where try_convert(time, col) is null;
```

This will show you the values that cannot be converted.  If you like, you can `NULL` them out so the `alter` will work:

```
update tblStop_times
    set col = NULL
    where try_convert(time, col) is null;
```

Comment: I tried this approach, and it fails with the error - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: I can post more details / screenshots if required.

Comment: I believe, try_convert is available from MSSQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: when I run below:
select arrival_time
from tblStop_times
where try_convert(time, arrival_time) is null; ... I got plenty of records with values exceeding 24:00:00 (i.e., 24:52:00, 24:09:00, and even 25:09:00)...I never knew I had values like this stored in table, btw, this table is based on GTFS, and I didn't check each record set as it has 70620 records. I will now maybe look for why is it there in the database to start with, column is named arrival_time, and has these unexpected values.

Comment: marking this solution as the correct one, as it did work fine for right / expected records.